# Decode array of integers as Date in Elm

Tags: elm

I'm trying to convert this json

```
{ "date": [2018, 2, 3] }
```

into this model

```
type alias MyModel = { date: Date }
```

I know how to decode it into a list

```
decoder = 
   decode MyModel (field "date" (list int))
```

but I can't figure out how to chain Decoders together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Json.Decode.index` to pull out values at known indices. You'll want the values at indices 0, 1, and 2, and then you can convert them to a string for use in `Date.fromString` like this:

```elm
import Date exposing (Date)
import Html exposing (Html, text)
import Json.Decode exposing (..)

dateDecoder : Decoder Date
dateDecoder =
    let
        toDateString y m d =
            String.join "-" (List.map toString [ y, m, d ])
    in
    map3 toDateString
        (index 0 int)
        (index 1 int)
        (index 2 int)
        |> andThen
            (\str ->
                case Date.fromString str of
                    Ok date ->
                        succeed date

                    Err err ->
                        fail err
            )
```

You could use the decoder like this:

```elm
decoder = 
    decode MyModel (field "date" dateDecoder)
```